# minify the minification

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Please put [minify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minify) as a tag-synonym for [minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minification).

Comment: It's quite obvious, but even with 100k rep from the JavaScript tag I don't have enough points to even vote on it.

Comment: `minification` is already a suggested synonym for [tag:minify], see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/minify/synonyms

Comment: OK, then the other way round if you like that better (imho `minification` is the better term). I just wanted to draw a little attention to it, as I cannot vote myself unfortunately.

Comment: We tend to have [tag:verb] tags not [tag:adjective] tags, hence minify and not minification.

Comment: @Joe: I thought we'd rather have nouns than verbs? I didn't suggest `minified` or `minificated` :-)

Comment: [tag:minify] is a verb ("to minify").  I guess [tag:minification] is actually a noun (the process is called minification).

Comment: Create a tag called `m10n` and mark both `minify` and `minification` as tag synonyms.  It only makes sense.

Comment: @Will: `m4y` safes another char :-P

Comment: Oooh!  Nice!  Let's use that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minification) has now been [*minified*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/minify/synonyms). Size reduction was 6 bytes.

Comment: 6 *characters* ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: In ASCII and UTF-8 it's 6 bytes *still*.

Comment: @Martijn, my brain runs in UCS-4 ;p

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Upgrade to [Python 3.3 or newer](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393) and free up some memory space! :-)